# jQuery - how to load content in a common div from two different events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a JS expert hence I am asking for some guidance. I have following scenario

1. page loads and commondiv is hidden
2. if user clicks button showeditform, I load editform in commondiv and show the commondiv
3. if user clicks button showeditform and editform is visible, remove it and hide commondiv
4. if user clicks button showpasswordform and if the editform is visible and I remove editform and show passwordform
5. if user clicks button showpasswordform and if the passwordform is visible, remove it and hide the common div
6. if user clicks button showeditform and if the passwordform is visible and I remove passwordform and show editform

As of now, I have set up flags and if elses but its not very good way to do it. How can I achieve this using minimum of jQuery code?

*Update*: Following is my attempt

```
$('a.editpo, a.resetpass').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlToCall = $(this).attr('href');
    var hyperlinkid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
    var targetId = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    var targetTrDiv = '#poformloadertr_'+targetId;
    var targetTdDiv = '#poformloadertd_'+targetId;
    var toToggle = $('#resetuserpassform_'+targetId).is(':visible') || $('#account-home-container-'+targetId).is(':visible') ;
    console.log(toToggle);
    if(toToggle == true || $(targetTdDiv).html()==''){
        $.ajax({
            url:urlToCall,
            success: function(html){
                $(targetTdDiv).html(html);
                $(targetTrDiv).show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(targetTrDiv).hide();
        $(targetTdDiv).html('');
    }

});
```

The `editpo` and `resetpass` are classes applied on hyperlinks in column of table, namely Edit personal info and reset pass, clicking these load up the form in a `tr>td`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $(function(){

        var $commonDiv = $("#commondiv");

        //Add the edit and password forms into common div and hide them initially
        $("#editform").hide().appendTo($commonDiv);
        $("#passwordform").hide().appendTo($commonDiv);

//Editing answer based on your comments.

        $(".showeditform").live('click', function(){

            if($("#editform").hasClass("loading")){//If form is already loading just return
               returnl
            }

            if(!$("#editform").is(":visible")){
               $("#editform").addClass("loading").load("EditFormUrl", function(){
                   $(this).removeClass("loading").show();
               });  
            }
            else{
               $("#editform").hide();
            }

            //Always hide the passwordform
            $("#passwordform").hide();
        }); 

       $(".showpasswordform").live('click', function(){

            if(!$("#passwordform").is(":visible")){
               $("#passwordform").addClass("loading").load("PasswordFormUrl", function(){
                   $(this).removeClass("loading").show();
               });  
            }
            else{
               $("#passwordform").hide();
            }

            //Always hide the editform
            $("#editform").hide();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Shakar the trouble is I load my forms on Ajax call, but still I like what you are saying

Comment: In that case you can execute my code in AJAX success callback after you add your forms into the dom(page).

Comment: If the 2 buttons are also coming from ajax response then you need to use jQuery `live` to attach the click handlers thanks.

Comment: to further complex it, the forms are loaded when you click the buttons :), actually a grid is loaded, in grid I have showeditform and showpasswordform classes applied to multiple "reset password" and "edit info" buttons, clicking those buttons must load the respective form using ajax call in a div, hope am clear now

Comment: Now your question is completely changed. I have already answered what you were looking for. But I will answer this also you should create a new question.

Comment: @Kumar - Take a look at my edited answer I have added the necessary code for your help, hope that works for you, thanks.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are saying, I will update the question with the code I have, sorry but I am not too good at JS and am just helping a friend :)

Comment: No issue dude..I am helping as well :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, have a look at the code I have pasted

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110215/jquery-help-in-optimising-refactoring-code, its shorter but can be still optimised.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this like a week ago, but the code is at home, where I am not at right now. But basically, you give your forms names in a array, and hide the ones that are not selected and if the one that is selected is clicked again use `.toggle();` function to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try. This is assuming you are storing your form HTML in JS. If you are storing it in a hidden container I can show you how to move that into the new parent or just copy the html into it.. hope this helps!

```
$("#commondiv").hide();

$("#showeditform").click(function(){
  if($("#commondiv").is(":visible")) {
    $("#commondiv").html("").hide();
  } else {
    $("#commondiv").html(editformHTML).show();
  }
});
$("#showpasswordform").click(function(){
  if($("#commondiv").is(":visible")) {
    $("#commondiv").html("").hide();
  } else {
    $("#commondiv").html(passwordformHTML).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: with JQuery you can also link methods in a chain. So .fadeOut(300).html(newHTML).fadeIn(300) will fade out the content over a 300ms period, load new HTML into the container, and fade the content back in over a period of 300ms.

Comment: here is my take http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110215/jquery-help-in-optimising-refactoring-code

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
  $('#showeditform').click(function()
  {
       if($('#commondiv').is(':visible'))
          $('#commondiv').hide();
       else 
          $('#commondiv').html('The text you want to set').show();

       if($('#passwordform').is(':visible'))
       {
           $('#passwordform').remove();
           $('#editform').show();
       }
  });

  $('#showpasswordform').click(function()
  {
      if($('#editform').is(':visible'))
      {
         $('#editform').hide();
         $('#passwordform').show();
      }

      if($('#passwordform').is(':visible'))
      {
         $('#passwordform').remove();
         $('#commondiv').hide();
      }
  });
```

Honestly, it sounds like your page is doing far too much on a single page. The rules shown above give me a kind of a headache.

Comment: `remove()` will remove the element from the dom. How will you show it next time?

Comment: its not doing anything special, gmail interface is what you can is doing far too much on a single page, but thanks or the hints

Comment: The OP said remove, not hide in certain situations. If he meant hide, then his question is being kind of vague.