# How to start optimising/refactoring jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jQuery code

```
$('a.editpo, a.resetpass').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlToCall = $(this).attr('href');
    var hyperlinkid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
    var targetId = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    var targetTrDiv = '#poformloadertr_'+targetId;
    var targetTdDiv = '#poformloadertd_'+targetId;
    var currentLink = $(this).html();
    /*Todo: refactor or shorten the following statement*/
    if((currentLink=='Edit' && $('#resetuserpassform_'+targetId).is(':visible')) 
        ||
       (currentLink=='Reset Pass' && $('#account-home-container-'+targetId).is(':visible'))
        ||
       ($(targetTdDiv).html() =='')
    ){
        $.ajax({
            url:urlToCall,
            success: function(html){
                $(targetTdDiv).html(html);
                $(targetTrDiv).show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(targetTrDiv).hide();
        $(targetTdDiv).html('');
    }
});
```

The editpo and resetpass are classes applied on hyperlinks in column of table, namely `Edit` and `Reset Pass`, clicking these load up the form in a table row, ids for the respective `tr` and `td` is `targetTrDiv` and `targetTdDiv`. I am not good at JS and specially jQuery, but would still be interested in any optimisations.

But I am especially interested in reducing the condition statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can optimize the following code:

```
   var urlToCall = $(this).attr('href');
   var hyperlinkid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
   var targetId = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
   var targetTrDiv = '#poformloadertr_'+targetId;
   var targetTdDiv = '#poformloadertd_'+targetId;
   var currentLink = $(this).html();
```

to:

```
   var wrappedSet$ = $(this);

   var urlToCall = wrappedSet$.attr('href');
   var hyperlinkid = '#'+wrappedSet$.attr('id');
   var targetId = wrappedSet$.attr('id').match(/\d+/);
   var targetTrDiv = '#poformloadertr_'+targetId;
   var targetTdDiv = '#poformloadertd_'+targetId;
   var currentLink = wrappedSet$.html();
```

**EDIT:** Also, you could remove the `currentLink=='Edit' &&` and `currentLink=='Reset Pass' &&` code snippets, because you can be sure that the right links were clicked using the class selector that you are using in your jQuery click handler (**a.editpo, a.resetpass**).

If you do that the codition statement will stays like this:

```
if(($('#resetuserpassform_'+targetId).is(':visible')) 
        ||
       ($('#account-home-container-'+targetId).is(':visible'))
        ||
       ($(targetTdDiv).html() =='')
    ){
       /* AJAX call goes here */
    }
```

Besides, and hopefully I'm wrong, it's very unlikely that the condition statement can be more optimized. The reason for concluding this is that you want to much specificity that is likely impossible to achieve in other way.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: oh! how can I forget this, thanks for pointing out, code changed :-)

Comment: I have to agree about the condition part, it can not be further optimised and the condition is if((link A is clicked and form for Link B is visible) OR  (link B is clicked and form for Link A is visible) OR (3rd condition)) but thanks :-)